# Почему не работает myExceptionClass в Java

Tags: java, исключения

Я создал класс `Exception`, который является наследником класса `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Но он не выбрасывается:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Какая проблема в моем коде?

```
class MyExeption extends ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

    public MyExeption(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ints = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
        try {
            ints[3] = 5;
        } catch (MyExeption ex){
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com

Comment: ints[3] = 5; there is no such element, so you can't change it/

Comment: Потому что этот эксепшн бросается самой джавой. Он знать не знает о вашем эксепшене. Что бы пользоваться своими эксепшенами их надо где-то кидать в коде, а не просто так. Почитайте про наследование.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете лишь возбудить собственное исключение при возникновении некоторых условий:

```
if(...) throw new MyException("mesage");
```

В вашем случае наследование от ArrayIndexOfBounsException в общем-то не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что ловить исключения можно:

- Самим типом исключения
- Предками текущего типа исключения

Например, у [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) такая цепочка наследования:

```
java.lang.Object
    java.lang.Throwable
        java.lang.Exception
            java.lang.RuntimeException
                java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
                    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

И в `catch` исключение [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) помимо самого исключения, смогут также поймать его предки: `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, `RuntimeException`, `Exception`, `Throwable`, `Object`

Answer (score 2):

В Java нет стандартного способа подменить стандартное исключение исключением определенным пользователем.

Пользовательские исключения должны быть явно выброшены оператором `throw`.